# Remove punctuation in the beginning of the word except special symbols

Tags: python, regex

**Question:** How use regex for removing punctuation from the beginning of words but to keep word `.NET`?

I've used the next regex:

```
text = 'Must-have skills: -.Net programming experience; -2 years experience in C++.'
newtext = re.sub(r'<.*?>|&nbsp;', ' ', text)
re.sub(r'[!,.:;—](?= |$)', ' ', newtext)
```

And I've had the next result:

```
'Must-have skills  -.Net programming experience  -2 years experience in C++ '
```

**Desired result:**

```
'Must-have skills  .Net programming experience  2 years experience in C++ '
```

**P.S.**:

I need to remove all punctuation before words. No need to remove only the dot in the word `.Net`. E.g. `-2` transform to `2`, but `-.Net` transform to `.Net`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185252/discussion-on-question-by-lemon-remove-punctuation-in-the-beginning-of-the-word).

Comment: I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
import re
text = 'Must-have skills: -.Net programming experience; -2 years experience in C++.'
text = re.sub(r'[!,.:;—](?= |$)', ' ', text)
print(re.sub(r'(?i)(?:(?!\.net\b|\b-\b)[^\w\s])+(?=[^\w\s]*\b)', '', text))
# => Must-have skills  .Net programming experience  2 years experience in C++
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/X3se9p).

**Details**

- `(?i)` - case insensitive mode on
- `(?:(?!\.net\b|\b-\b)[^\w\s])+` - any punctuation char (`[^\w\s]`), 1 or more occurrences, as many as possible, that does not start any of the sequences:

  - `\.net\b` - `.net` as whole word
  - `|` - or
  - `\b-\b` - a hyphen enclosed with word chars
- `(?=[^\w\s]*\b)` - a positive lookahead that requires 0+ punctuation chars followed with a word boundary position immediately to the right of the current location.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex to find all points that are not followed by Net.

```
[!,.:;-](?!Net|$|\W)
```

Then use Regex.Replace() to remove the matches from your text.